# how to call a method with an Object parameter instead of the actual parameter type in java?

Tags: java

Hello everyone i just want to know how can we call a method passing an object type as parameter instead of the actual parameters.Suppose i have a class

```
public class Helper {

    public void showEntity(Message msg)
    {
        System.out.println(msg.sessionID);
    }

}
```

now i want to call showEntity Method but i only have information about the name of the parameter's type i.e Message naturally i'll create an object of this class by using Class.forName().getClass and then will create a new instance and all that.

```
Class<?> clazz=Class.forName(nameOfParameterType).getClass();
Object obj=clazz.newInstance();
```

Now the question arises how will i actually call the showEntity method by passing in the created Object type instead of the actual Message Type beacuse calling showEntity(obj) gives error and i dont want to use reflection to cal this method i want to do it via

```
Helper helper=new Helper();
helper.showEntity(obj) //gives error
```

Comment: Create a `showEntity(Object msg)` in the Helper class?

Comment: I'd advice redesigning (if possible). Such "tricks" inhibits type safety.

Comment: This smells awfully like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Could you explain your use case?

Comment: `Class<? extends Message> clazz`. Java is a strongly typed language, use that to your advantage don't fight against it.

Comment: @Turing85 there will only be available the information about the actual type of the parameter of the showEntity method. How to actually create it and call showEntity by passing an object of that type?

Comment: @BoristheSpider precisely but i dont have a "Message" type anywhere(i mean not in my current code block) and thats what i am asking i have just got its name

Comment: Again: Why will only this information be available? Please be more elaborate. As @SomeName already suggested, I suspect that some major redesign is necessary.

Comment: Where would you get an instance of a random type? If you can create it without arguments and without knowledge of its type then why pass anything at all to this method??

Comment: 'Gives error' how? What error?

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is: by casting, like `(Message) thatObjThatIsAMessage`. Or, by using reflection to invoke that method (which would of course only add madness here).

The real answer is: you are going down the very wrong rabbit hole.

You do not invoke methods and pass arbitrary parameters because you can. You do that because you **need** to.

If you don't know what parameter to pass to a method, why do you think you should invoke that method in the first place? That is like "I don't know what is happening when dialing 911 (or whatever your emergency number is), but I have a phone in front of me, so I will do that now".

And of course: the fact that you then consider to use **reflection** just adds to that. Reflection and doing things `byName()` is something you absolutely only do when you don't have any other choice! Who says for example that your Message class has a no-argument constructor, so that `newInstance()` would actually work out?! What if it has one today, but the person owning it removes that tomorrow. You will only learn that at runtime! This is not meant to belittle you, but honestly: a person who does not know how to cast an object, that person is lacking basic Java knowledge. Reflection is completely beyond what you should be dealing with at that skill level.

Long story short: stop right now, and determine what you **really** have and want to do. I guarantee you: it is not to call a method you don't have appropriate parameters for!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I am missing something, but you can just cast it. That should work fine in case you are certain the type can only be Message:

```
helper.showEntity((Message)obj);
```

I would just for sake of code-quality add some kind of check before that call and throw IllegalArgumentException in case type is not Message.

Comment: Chris the point is how shall i get hold to the Message? since i am just getting its name

Comment: "*I would just for sake of code-quality add some kind of check before that call*" - A better solution would be one that [fails fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast), prefferably at compile-time.

Comment: OK, so you are using reflection (newInstance() on Class object) here and the interface just defines Object as return type. How do you want to resolve this type-check at compile time here...?

Comment: By a redesign. There is something wrong in the overall architecture of this code. How exactly I would redesign I cannot tell since I do not konw the domain of the code.

Answer (score 1):

1) Don't do `clazz.newInstance();` but do `clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();` to ensure to trap any checked exception.

2) Never write such a code : `helper.showEntity((Message)obj);`.
A best idiom is to cast as assignment to  `newInstance()` in order to centralize the instantiation/cast logic and its exceptions:

```
Class<?> clazz = ...;
try {
    Messsage message = (Message) clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
    // do something with message

} catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | InstantiationException | ClassCastException e) {
    // handle the exception
}
```

3) Favor `Supplier` to reflection when you can.
If the class is defined at compile time somewhere and here it seems to be the case since you expect a specific class (`Message`), you should do something like that :

```
Helper helper=new Helper();
helper.showEntity(getNewMessage().get());

Supplier<Message> getNewMessage(){
   return Message::new;
}
```

Comment: If you are comfortable with, sure don't change anything :) The model is this one : https://www.ebay.de/itm/Konig-Neurath-Okay-II-Burodrehstuhl-Vollausstattung-Neu/123522894406?hash=item1cc289ca46:g:TnkAAOSwMg5b-BS1:rk:2:pf:0 Concerning yours, that is really original. I didn't think that without a back support it could be so comfortable.

Answer (score -1):

`helper.showEntity((Message)obj) //gives error` - you need a cast

Runnable version:

```
public class SO {


public static class Helper {
    public void showEntity(Message msg) {
        System.out.println(msg.sessionID);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

    Class<?> clazz= Class.forName(Message.class.getName());
    Message msg = (Message) clazz.newInstance();
    msg.sessionID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    new Helper().showEntity(msg);// here the instance is cast to Message and should work.

}
```

Comment: This is a compile time construct - it by definition cannot replace refelection in the general case - without more information from the OP we do now know what the specifc case the user is trying to solve for.

Answer (score -1):

One option as following. In this case the type you can pass to showEntity is restricted to type Message and its sub classes which i think should be the case, else you will not know how to get an instance of the object and which method to call as you are not open of reflection APIs. Having no knowledge of what type is being passed calls for usage of reflection APIs.

```
public class Helper {

    public void showEntity(String msgImpl) {
        try {
            System.out.println(getMessageInstance(msgImpl).getSessionId());
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Message getMessageInstance(String msgImpl)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<? extends Message> msg = Class.forName(msgImpl).asSubclass(Message.class);
        return msg.newInstance();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Helper h = new Helper();
        h.showEntity("com.foo.Message");
    }
}

public class Message {

    public String getSessionId() {
        return "SessionID";
    }
}
```